# React Native Image not showing on Android Emulator

Tags: android, image, react-native

the image comes through a GET request from a json server
the other data is appearing less the image

What can this be?

```
<ProductList
          data={products}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id}
          ListFooterComponent={<View />}
          ListFooterComponentStyle={{
            height: 80,
          }}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <Product>
              <ProductImage source={{ uri: item.image_url }} />
              <ProductTitle>{item.title}</ProductTitle>
              <PriceContainer>
                <ProductPrice>{formatValue(item.price)}</ProductPrice>
                <ProductButton
                  testID={`add-to-cart-${item.id}`}
                  onPress={() => handleAddToCart(item)}
                >
                  <FeatherIcon size={20} name="plus" color={colors.iconColor} />
                </ProductButton>
              </PriceContainer>
            </Product>
          )}
        />
```

Comment: could you print item object ? the uri is accesible (or you are working in local)? also show ProductImage component

Comment: I am working local, the image is in https @anthonywillismuñoz

Comment: you can open it in your browser ?

Comment: @anthonywillismuñoz yes, in IOS simulator is running, but not in android simulator

Comment: you try in a real device and put your productImage component. But not make sense at all